# how to train a maxent classifier

Tags: twitter, sentiment-analysis, opennlp, maxent

[Project stack : Java, Opennlp, Elasticsearch (datastore) , twitter4j to read data from twitter]

I intend to use maxent classifier to classify tweets. I understand that the initial step is to train the model. From the documentation I found that we have a GISTrainer based train method to train the model. I have managed to put together a simple piece of code which makes use of opennlp's maxent classifier to train the model and predict the outcome.

I have used two files postive.txt and negative.txt to train the model

Contents of positive.txt

```
positive    This is good
positive    This is the best
positive    This is fantastic
positive    This is super
positive    This is fine 
positive    This is nice
```

Contents of negative.txt

```
negative    This is bad
negative    This is ugly
negative    This is the worst
negative    This is worse
negative    This sucks
```

And the java methods below generate the outcome.

```
@Override
public void trainDataset(String source, String destination) throws Exception {
    File[] inputFiles = FileUtil.buildFileList(new File(source)); // trains both positive and negative.txt
    File modelFile = new File(destination);
    Tokenizer tokenizer = SimpleTokenizer.INSTANCE;
    CategoryDataStream ds = new CategoryDataStream(inputFiles, tokenizer);
    int cutoff = 5;
    int iterations = 100;
    BagOfWordsFeatureGenerator bowfg = new BagOfWordsFeatureGenerator();
    DoccatModel model = DocumentCategorizerME.train("en", ds, cutoff,iterations, bowfg);
    model.serialize(new FileOutputStream(modelFile));
}

@Override
public void predict(String text, String modelFile) {
    InputStream modelStream = null;
    try{
        Tokenizer tokenizer = SimpleTokenizer.INSTANCE;
        String[] tokens = tokenizer.tokenize(text);
        modelStream = new FileInputStream(modelFile);
        DoccatModel model = new DoccatModel(modelStream);
        BagOfWordsFeatureGenerator bowfg = new BagOfWordsFeatureGenerator(); 
        DocumentCategorizer categorizer = new DocumentCategorizerME(model, bowfg);
        double[] probs   = categorizer.categorize(tokens);
        if(null!=probs && probs.length>0){
            for(int i=0;i<probs.length;i++){
                System.out.println("double[] probs index  " + i + " value " + probs[i]);
            }
        }
        String label = categorizer.getBestCategory(probs);
        System.out.println("label " + label);
        int bestIndex = categorizer.getIndex(label);
        System.out.println("bestIndex " + bestIndex);
        double score = probs[bestIndex];
        System.out.println("score " + score);
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally{
        if(null!=modelStream){
            try {
                modelStream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        String outputModelPath = "/home/**/sd-sentiment-analysis/models/trainPostive";
        String source = "/home/**/sd-sentiment-analysis/sd-core/src/main/resources/datasets/";
        MaximunEntropyClassifier me = new MaximunEntropyClassifier();
        me.trainDataset(source, outputModelPath);
        me.predict("This is bad", outputModelPath);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I have the following questions.

1) How do I iteratively train a model? Also, how do I add new sentences/words to the model ? Is there a specific format for the data file? I found that the file needs to have a minimum of two words separated by a tab. Is my understanding valid?
2) Are there any publicly available data sets that I can use to train the model? I found some sources for movie reviews. The project I'm working on involves not just movie reviews but also other things such as product reviews, brand sentiments etc. 
3)  [This](https://opennlp.apache.org/documentation/1.5.3/manual/opennlp.html#opennlp.ml.maxent) helps to an extent. Is there a working example somewhere publicly available? I couldn't find the documentation for maxent.

Please help me out. I am kind'a blocked on this.

Answer (score 0):

1) you can store the samples in a database. I used accumulo once for this. Then at some interval you rebuild the model and reprocess your data.
2) the format is: categoryname space sample newline. No tabs
3) sounds like you want to combine general sentiment with a topic or entity. You could use a name finder or just regex to find the entity or add the entity to your class labels for the doccat include a product name etc , then your samples would have to be very specific

Comment: Hi Mark,
Thanks for the reply. The idea is to capture the sentiment of a particular entity. The entity could be a brand, a product or a company. I played around with the data format and it worked only when I had the data separated by a tab from the category. 
I am currently looking into https://opennlp.apache.org/documentation/1.5.3/manual/opennlp.html#opennlp.ml 

Is there a working classifier using maxent or naive bayes?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, you have to **completely retrain** a MaxEnt model if you want to add new training samples. It **cannot be done incrementally** on-line.

The default input format for opennlp maxent is a textual file where each line represents a single sample.
A sample is composed of tokens (features) delimited by whitespace. During training, the first token represents the outcome.

Take a look at my minimal working example here :
[Training models using openNLP maxent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24897358/training-models-using-opennlp-maxent/26757661#26757661)